# When to use Expression

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, expression-trees

I am trying to determine what to use ...

I have a requirement to pass an `IEnumerable<TSource>` to a function that writes the entity members' values to file. Here is what the IEnumerable looks like:

```
var persons = new[] {
    new Person {
        RecordID = 0,
        PersonFName = "Joe",
        PersonMName = "",
        PersonLName = "Smith",
        PersonZip="75227"
    }, 
    new Person {
        RecordID = 1,
        PersonFName = "Mary",
        PersonMName = "Hada",
        PersonLName = "Lamb",
        PersonZip="75217"
    }};
```

What is the best way to pass the IEnumerable to a function that reads each entity so I can read each field value?

I was thinking that I would use something like:

```
void WriteData<TSource>(Expression<IEnumerable<Person>> expression)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

I'm having trouble finding resources that explain how to determine when you should use an Expression versus just passing IEnumerable. And then, how do I create the Expression that reflects `persons` ?

Ideally, it seems like I would call WriteData like so:

```
WriteData(persons);
```

Am I even headed in the right direction?

Comment: if you are really interested in learning how to leverage expressions and the `IQueryable` interface, I highly recommend reading Matt Warren's [LINQ: Building an IQueryable provider series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx).  Warning: Metaprogramming can be complex and requires time and patience

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no reason to use an expression tree there. If you just want to fetch all the properties by reflection, I suggest you do that - expression trees won't really help you do that though.

Note that the choice is rarely between `Expression` and `IEnumerable<T>` - it's usually either between an expression tree and a delegate, or between `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: Thank you ...just trying to figure out what I need to use. I didn't want to use reflection ...but I didn't really have a better solution either.

Comment: @IAbstract: Then it's unclear what you *do* want to do. Why do you think expression trees are adding anything? `Expression<IEnumerable<Person>>` isn't even a realistic type, as the `T` in `Expression<T>` should always *really* be a delegate type.

Comment: Okay, well, that makes sense - `Expression<IEnumerable<Person>>` looked really strange and didn't seem right. I'm venturing into something a little different without any other expertise to pull from.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you'd do with an expression but this is roughly what I'd do using reflection.

```
public void WriteData<T>(IEnumerable<T> objects) where T : class
{
  foreach (var obj in objects)
  {
    WriteObjectData(obj);
  }
}

private void WriteObjectData<T>(T obj) where T : class
{
    foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        // Use propertyInfo.GetValue to get the value from obj. 
    }
}
```

You could specify an interface instead of `where T:class` to limit the methods to just your data objects if you wanted to.

Comment: Right, I think this is what @JonSkeet is saying I should do.